# Crystal Report Next Button doesnt working properly

Tags: crystal-reports

I am Working in Visual Studio 2008 and using the packaged Crystal Reports (version 10.5). I have a couple pages that use the Crystal Reports Viewer to display the reports, and I use the CR V navigation buttons to page through large reports.

Problem: The Next button only goes to page 2. The Previous button goes to Page 1 every time.

When i click the next button from page 2. then it doesn't work. I want to solve this problem Event Independent. I don't know is there anything named Event Independent or not but i want a solution that will not based on any event.

can anyone help me?